# Parsing streams from assets has bad performance

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am reading assets from the device with the android AssetManager and try to parse them within the application. The problem is, that the parsing of a single asset takes a very long time (~10s) compared to the size of the streams. I have 3 files included as assets, which have a size from 1.6MB to 2.2MB and should take less time to parse.

Reading the assets:

```cs
            AssetManager manager = this.Assets;
            Stream[] assets = new Stream[]
            {
                manager.Open("arial.fta"),
                manager.Open("consolas.fta"),
                manager.Open("comicsans.fta")
            };
```

Parsing the stream:

```cs
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(assets[0]);
            int width = reader.ReadInt32();
            int height = reader.ReadInt32();
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    Color col = new Color();
                    col.R = reader.ReadByte();
                    col.G = reader.ReadByte();
                    col.B = reader.ReadByte();

                    bmp.PixelData[x, y] = col;
                }
            }
```

Console log while parsing: (continues like this for 10 sec)

```
06-08 13:20:02.920 D/Mono    (26245): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 12 objects 18 opaque 2 colors 12 colors-bridged 12 colors-visible 12 xref 0 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.08ms tarjan 0.08ms scc-setup 0.08ms gather-xref 0.07ms xref-setup 0.07ms cleanup 0.08ms
06-08 13:20:02.920 D/Mono    (26245): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 11.05ms
06-08 13:20:02.920 D/Mono    (26245): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 2.93ms, stw 6.51ms promoted 163K major size: 848K in use: 224K los size: 3204K in use: 2231K
06-08 13:20:03.964 D/Mono    (26245): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 0 objects 0 opaque 0 colors 0 colors-bridged 0 colors-visible 12 xref 0 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.08ms tarjan 0.08ms scc-setup 0.08ms gather-xref 0.07ms xref-setup 0.07ms cleanup 0.06ms
06-08 13:20:03.965 D/Mono    (26245): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 0.55ms
...
```

I would be really glad if someone could help me to improve performance.

On a side note: The stream.Position cant be set and always throws an error (System.NotSupportedException). Does anybody know, why this happens

Comment: About 600000 pixels in an asset ? How long do you think it should take ? Remove two of the `ReadByte()` methods and see what happens.

Comment: Yes you are probably right ill try to minimize the amount the stream needs to be accessed. I run this before on windows and it only took around 60ms, I hoped it wouldnt be 166 times longer as it is now but the hardware difference is probably greater than i thought. Thanks